# Views 2 filter: field x = current user's ID

Tags: entities, users, views

So I have a view and a filter with field x. I want this field x to be equal to the user ID of the current user.

When adding the filter I'm asked to insert a value, if I insert the value by hand, e.g. 1, the right content is displayed for that user.
However, I wanna automate this system for the rest of the users.

I tried things like %uid in the value box but this doesn't seem to work.

any ideas?

I'm using Drupal 6 and Views 2.

Answer (score 1):

There is a filter called `User: Current` which will "Filter the view to the currently logged in user."

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I have a custom table with uids. I want to say custom table: uid = user : current.

Comment: Hmm, i'm still not sure that I understand the question. Could you add the User: Current filter and then add the User: Uid field? If not, I suggest expanding your original question.

Comment: okay so i have table A with all the users, table B with all the nodes and finally table C with 2 fields, uid and nid. Now, I have managed to read all the nodes in table C using the Data module which allows me to connect the field to the content type (all the nodes in table B). Now I just want to display the content which belongs to the current user logged in. User:current won't work because views doesn't know what uid is, it think its just some field. so i wanna add a filter which says, table C: uid = current user.

Comment: Figured it out. Add the field in arguments and as a default value say get logged in user's ID.